# Checking if a number is a Simber

Tags: c++

A simber is defined as a positive integer in which any odd digit, if present, occurs an odd number of times, 1414414 is a simber. 4 is even and it appears four time and 1 is odd and it appears 3 times.

Here are my variables:

```
int is_simber(int n) 
{
    int numberOfTimes = 0, length = 1, x = n; 
    bool answer; 
    vector <int> nmbrs = vector <int>(); 


    //get how many digits are in the integer

    do
    { 
       x /= 10; 
       length++; 
    }
    while(x != 0) 


    //get the digits in the integer

    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++) 
    {
      nmbrs.push_back(((n/10^i) % 10); 
    }


    //checking how many times a digit occurs and also testing to see if the digits
    //meet the requirements

    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<length; j++) 
        {
            if (nmbrs.at(i) == nmbrs.at(j))
            {
                numberOfTimes++; 
            }
        }

        if (nmbrs.at(i) % 2 == 0 && numberOfTimes % 2 == 0) 
        {
          answer = true; 
        }

        else if(nmbrs.at(i) % 2 == 1 && numberOfTimes % 2 == 1)
        { 
            answer = true; 
        }

        else if(nmbrs.at(i) % 2 == 0 && numberOfTimes % 2 == 1)
        {
            answer = false; 
            break; 
        }

        else if(nmbrs.at(i) % 2 == 1 && numberOfTimes % 2 == 0)
        {
            answer = false; 
            break;
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Time to do some debugging. You need to figure out where the problem is. Or if there are multiple problems, where's the first one. Insert some printouts and see where things go wrong. Does the do/while loop calculate the correct length? Does the first for loop get the digits right?

Comment: It prints true even if false. Let me check the loops.

Comment: Is this your actual code, copied and pasted? I see a syntax error that'll prevent it from even compiling.

Comment: Yes. It is. Where is it?

Comment: You tell us where it is (it's your code, and you've supposedly compiled and run it to know it isn't working). You've also not explained a specific problem. *What's wrong with my code? It's supposed to do this thing.* has no meaning if you don't tell us what input you're providing and what it's doing instead of what it should. If you want help here, post your actual code, state the problem clearly, provide the input needed to reproduce the problem, and explain why the results are not what you expect, and **ask a specific question**. "What's wrong with my code?" is a far cry from **specific**.

Comment: It is supposed to check if a number is a simber but it prints true for the number even if he number is not a simber.

Comment: As suggested, try adding some printing inside the function to see if which variables contain what they should and which don't. If you do that, you'll find `nmbrs` doesn't contain the values you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your code has [compilation errors](http://ideone.com/BiqsE6).
2. `^` is [Binary XOR Operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm). You can't expect it to produce `pow(10,i)`. So replace `nmbrs.push_back(((n/10^i) % 10);` with `nmbrs.push_back(((n/pow(10,i)) % 10);`
3. When I was able to remove the compilation errors, i realized your code has logical errors too. As your given definition of simber, `int is_simber(int n)` should be fair and simple.

```cpp
bool is_simber( int n )
{
    if ( n<0 ) return false; // simber is a positive integer

    int digitCount[10] = {}; // initializing all with 0;
    // digitCount array holds the number of occurance of a digit
    // so d[1] holds the number of times 1 occurred
    // d[2] holds the number of times 2 occurred and so on ... 

    while( n ){
        int d = n%10;
        n /= 10;
        digitCount[d]++;
    }

    // we just have to check 
    // any odd digit, if present, occurs an odd number of times

    for( int i=1; i<=9; i= i+2) // Attention i=i+2, to iterate over just odd numbers
    {
        if( digitCount[i] != 0 && digitCount[i]%2 == 0 ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What about the even ones?

Comment: Suggest not using `pow` as it is a floating point function and so may incur rounding errors when used with integers.

Comment: Rafaf, it's doesn't compile. Has a warning about increment and an error about token '=='

Comment: It now compiles but wig wrong answers. I'll try fixing the part I see wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My definition of `is_simber`

```
inline bool is_even(int n) { return n % 2 == 0; }

bool is_simber(int n) {
    if (n < 0) return false;
    int digits[10] = {0};
    for (; n; n /= 10) ++digits[n % 10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
        if (!is_even(digits[i]) && is_even(digits[i + 1])) return false;
    return true;
}
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1c3e812ea53208f)</kbd>